# Processor Power Management

Tags: 16.04

I am using a AMD FX(tm)-9590 Eight-Core Processor × 8  on Ubuntu 16.04. I've had freezing issues come up on Windows 10 before, these were easily solved by limiting the maximum processor state to 99% rather than 100%. I need to be able to do this on my Ubuntu machine now as well because the freezing issues are occurring when doing installations.

Anyone aware of how to change this settings, as I was unable to find specifics that were permanent changes for AMD and Ubuntu. An example of the windows fix can be found [here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/processor-power-management-windows). Thanks!

EDIT: I've temporarily resolved the problem by changing the BIOS setting to allow the CPU to run up to 100 degrees C. I'm sure this will inevitably melt my pc if I use this temp too often. But it'll work until I solve the problem.

Comment: in that case you should also cap your cpu's frequency to as lower value possible, you'll damage your CPU really quickly otherwise

Comment: Yes sadly this only caused the cpu to heat up to the new limit and quit, still looking for a resolution to the issue as i'm unable to continue my project otherwise.